# Prioritizing classes for database inserts

Tags: c#, database

I need to create a service to insert data into a database in a particular order as the table has foreign key constraints. Dropping constraints and re-adding it is not preferred, so I am trying to insert with child data first then parent data.

To summarize it with an example

- Titan <-- Energy
- Player <-- Titan

Energy has to be inserted first then Titan then Player.

I tried to create a grid to represent whether a class has another class reference.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Type [] tables_toScan = new Type[] { typeof(Titan), typeof(Player), typeof(Energy) };

            int table_scan_length = tables_toScan.Count();

            int[,] grid_table = new int[table_scan_length, table_scan_length];

            IDictionary<Type, int> position_space = new Dictionary<Type, int>();
            for (int i = table_scan_length-1; i > -1; i--)
            {
                position_space.Add(tables_toScan[i], i);
            }

            foreach (var type in tables_toScan)
            {
                PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = type.GetProperties();
                IEnumerable<Type> typeList = propertyInfos.Select(x => x.PropertyType).Distinct();

                foreach (var currentPropertyType in typeList)
                {
                    if (tables_toScan.Contains(currentPropertyType))
                    {
                        grid_table[position_space[currentPropertyType], position_space[type]] = 1;
                    }
                    else if (currentPropertyType.IsGenericType &&
                      currentPropertyType != typeof(string) && typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(currentPropertyType))
                    {
                        var collectionUnderLyingType = currentPropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                        if (tables_toScan.Contains(collectionUnderLyingType))
                        {
                            grid_table[position_space[collectionUnderLyingType], position_space[type]] = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class Titan
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public IList<Energy> energy { get; set; }
    }

    class Player
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public Titan titan { get; set; }
    }

    class Energy
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string color { get; set; }
    }
```

I would like to have ordering classes for a given scenario:

- Energy -- > 1,
- Titan --> 2 and Player --> 3

print grid gives

```
           Titan      Player     Energy
Titan      0          1          0
Player     0          0          0
Energy     1          0          0
```

Comment: If the classes are known to you why don't you just use them straight forward to insert first energy, second titan and third player data? Its not clear what problem you are trying to solve by knowing the class relationships at runtime.

Comment: Its dynamic and I cant do the same for N number of classes getting relations manually and ordering. I need to use it for what ever input is given for insight purpose i gave those 3 classes